# Do I need to use User Tracking if I use Admob?

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect, apptrackingtransparency

I added the App Tracking Transparency dialog in my code to ask users if they allow tracking.
My app was rejected in the App Store Connect -

> Your app contains NSUserTrackingUsageDescription, indicating that you will request permission to track users.

But now I'm not sure if I really need to use tracking?
I simply use Admob to show ads, and have only one app, so I don't need to collect data?

I have no idea what type of ads Admob shows the users (personalized/not personalized)
I assumed that everyone who uses Admob should show that User Tracking permission for ios14+, but do I really? Why do I need to collect data?

Comment: There must be more to the message Apple have you. As well as having the NSUserTrackingUserDescription does your app actually show the dialog? Does your usage description accurately describe how your app will track users?  Note that even if your code doesn't track users directly, you include AdMob and that code will track users if they have permission.  It doesn't matter how many apps you have. Data from all of the apps on a users device that use AdMob will correlate data. That is the point of ATT

Comment: Yes, my app uses the dialog, I added it in my code because I thought that I have to since I use ADMOB, but do I really ? So everyone who uses Admob must show this dialog?

Comment: Yes.  Everyone who uses Admob must show this dialog.  During review they will detect if your code (or any included frameworks) references the advertising identifier.  If there is a reference and the app tracking permission framework isn't shown then your app will be rejected.

Comment: But when I use Admob and don't show that dialog and don't add NSUserTrackingUsageDescription to info.plist  , my app is not rejected

Answer (score 2):

no you don't need NSUserTrackingUsageDescription if you use Admob.
you can use this permission like if you want to get advertising id of the device.

and remember to delete NSUserTrackingUsageDescription from info.plist if you don't use it so your app don't get rejected.

also if you used this permission remember to change the privacy of the app on apple store,
go to app privacy and in data types section click edit and select Identifiers (Device ID) and set this one as used for tracking purposes. and make sure that this is the only one selected as used for tracking.